# Rails Scope for JSONB Hash with Array for Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I am using a JSONB column where the data is stored as { key => [value, value, value ] }
How do I write a scope that returns records which contain a particular value in the array of a particular key?

I've figured out how to search simple JSON Hashes;

```
scope :rice_flour, -> { where("ingredients ->> 'flour' = ?", "rice") }
```

...but this query type still escapes me.  Everything I have looked up lays things out in raw SQL commands, and I am looking for how to write tidy Rails Scopes.

Comment: "particular value in it's hash" you mean "particular value in the array"?

Comment: what is your postgres version?

Comment: Meant I want to query for records containing a particular value in the array of a particular key. Postgres 10.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `@>` operator:

```
postgres@/> select '["a", "b"]'::jsonb @> '["a"]';
+------------+
| ?column?   |
|------------|
| True       |
+------------+

postgres@/> select '["a", "b"]'::jsonb @> '["c"]';
+------------+
| ?column?   |
|------------|
| False      |
+------------+
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html

Your scope will be like:

```
scope :rice_flour, -> { 
   .where("ingredients -> 'flour' @> '[\"rice\"]'::jsonb")
}
```

This will generate a SQL like:

```
WHERE (ingredients -> 'flour' @> '["rice"]'::jsonb)
```

Assuming `flour` is the key and `rice` is one of the values in the array.

Comment: I am one reputation short of being able to Vote for your answer. :-/  Thanks emaillenin for the information and pointer.  Works perfectly.